# Can I maximize windows on a second monitor?

Tags: display

I recently added a second monitor. I want to be able to keep a window maximized on this screen. Clicking the maximize button when in this monitor causes the alert sound to play and the window does not maximize.

How can I maximize a window on the secondary display?

Comment: I am not seeing this kind of issue when I try this with my MacBook Pro and second display. What version of macOS are you running? Which application does this happen with? Does this happen with other applications - specifically stock apps? What is the brand of monitor and how are you connecting it to your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I am now able to maximize windows on my second display.

The only change I made was to try it with Finder per @drivec's comment about stock apps vs. other apps.

The direct answer to my question is: Yes you can maximize windows on a second display.

I have no idea why it did not work earlier.